# replace values of dataframe with search in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have two dataframes:

Ranking
[image: Text] (picture as example)

```
structure(list(`1` = c("GLD", "GLD", "GLD", "GLD", "GLD", "GLD"
), `2` = c("VT", "VT", "VT", "VT", "BIL", "VT"), `3` = c("BIL", 
"BIL", "BIL", "BIL", "VT", "BIL"), `4` = c("UUP", "UUP", "UUP", 
"UUP", "UUP", "UUP"), `5` = c("RSP", "RSP", "RSP", "RSP", "RSP", 
"RSP")), row.names = c("2008-02-01", "2008-03-01", "2008-04-01", 
"2008-05-01", "2008-06-01", "2008-07-01"), class = "data.frame")
```

Returns
[image: Text] (picture as example)

```
structure(list(BIL = c(0.04, -0.22, -0.02, 0.13, 0.07, -0.07), 
    GLD = c(-6, -4.16, 0.92, 4.52, -1.44, -9.29), RSP = c(-2.24, 
    5.72, 2.65, -10.16, -0.5, 2.96), UUP = c(-2.4, 0.94, 0.44, 
    -0.97, 1.02, 5.37), VT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.85)), row.names = c("2008-02-01", 
"2008-03-01", "2008-04-01", "2008-05-01", "2008-06-01", "2008-07-01"
), class = "data.frame")
```

What I want is create a new dataframe with the same structure than Ranking but with the value of Returns.

Something like this
[image: Text]

Right now I´m using two For Loop:

```
for (i in rownames(Ranking)){
  
  for (x in colnames(Ranking)){
    
      stock = as.character(Ranking[i,x])
    
      Solution[i,x] = Returns[i,stock]
    }
    
  }
```

But I would like to use something more efficient. Any idea?

Comment: sorry, what is the dput? about dates: yes, both dataframe has the same nrow and rownames.

Comment: Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). Use an alternative [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: structure(list(`1` = c("GLD", "GLD", "GLD", "GLD", "GLD", "GLD"
), `2` = c("VT", "VT", "VT", "VT", "BIL", "VT"), `3` = c("BIL", 
"BIL", "BIL", "BIL", "VT", "BIL"), `4` = c("UUP", "UUP", "UUP", 
"UUP", "UUP", "UUP"), `5` = c("RSP", "RSP", "RSP", "RSP", "RSP", 
"RSP")), row.names = c("2008-02-01", "2008-03-01", "2008-04-01", 
"2008-05-01", "2008-06-01", "2008-07-01"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: structure(list(BIL = c(0.04, -0.22, -0.02, 0.13, 0.07, -0.07), 
    GLD = c(-6, -4.16, 0.92, 4.52, -1.44, -9.29), RSP = c(-2.24, 
    5.72, 2.65, -10.16, -0.5, 2.96), UUP = c(-2.4, 0.94, 0.44, 
    -0.97, 1.02, 5.37), VT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.85)), row.names = c("2008-02-01", 
"2008-03-01", "2008-04-01", "2008-05-01", "2008-06-01", "2008-07-01"
), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a matrix of row/column indexes - row from the `row` index (or from row.names, matched - if the row names are the same, then we don't need to match), and column index from `matching` the values from 'Ranking' with the column names of 'Returns', extract the 'Returns' value and assign it to 'Solution' new data created

```
Solution <- Ranking
Solution[] <- type.convert(Returns[cbind(c(row(Ranking)), 
      match(as.matrix(Ranking), colnames(Returns)))], as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
> Solution
               1     2     3     4      5
2008-02-01 -6.00  0.00  0.04 -2.40  -2.24
2008-03-01 -4.16  0.00 -0.22  0.94   5.72
2008-04-01  0.92  0.00 -0.02  0.44   2.65
2008-05-01  4.52  0.00  0.13 -0.97 -10.16
2008-06-01 -1.44  0.07  0.00  1.02  -0.50
2008-07-01 -9.29 -1.85 -0.07  5.37   2.96
```